# Корректность трех фраз

Tags: стилистика

Какие фразы из трех корректны, а какие нет?
1. Мравинский дирижирует Чайковским и Бетховеном.
2. Мравинский дирижирует музыкой Чайковского и Бетховена.
3. Оркестр Санкт-Петербургской филармонии под управлением Мравинского исполняет произведения Чайковского и Бетховена.

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос. Или объясните, в чем для Вас сложность. Здесь обычно не отвечают на вопросы с формулировками домашних заданий.

Comment: Конкретизирую:
есть очень известный и серьезный музыкальный веб-сайт medichi.tv. В его контент на русском языке включены статьи с описанием транслируемых музыкальных событий.

Comment: Вы свои проблемы с русским языком конкретизируйте, а не источник. Ну какие вот сложности с последним вариантом? Ну первые два - ладно, можно спросить, просто для того, чтобы убедиться, что косноязычие... А третий-то?!

Comment: Так вот, я обнаружила, что многие (большинство) заголовков этих статей некорректны. Права я, или нет? Эти заголовки составлены по шаблону 1-й фразы из моего вопроса на вашем сайте.

Comment: Вот именно, что третий вариант категорически отвергается редакцией этого сайта, а мне режет слух 1-й вариант, который они выдают за истину.

Comment: Ну так это же и надо написать было в вопросе, что спор возник о том-то и то-то. И что именно слух режет. ))) Ладно, чем мог - ответил.

Comment: Подтверждаю: ЛУИ ЛАНГРЕ ДИРИЖИРУЕТ МОЦАРТОМ – С РИЧАРДОМ ГУД. Не заморачиваются, что ж тут сделаешь..

Answer (score 1):

> Так вот, я обнаружила, что многие (большинство) заголовков этих статей
>   некорректны. Права я, или нет?

Дирижировать ни музыкой/музыку, ни тем более - композиторами, нельзя. насколько знаю - даже в жестком профжаргоне. Дирижируют оркестром. Так что с первыми двумя всё ясно.

Какие проблемы с третьим заголовком, просто не представляю.

(+)

На сайт попасть не могу. Да и бог с ним. 
Можете показать им словарь.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

> ДИРИЖИРОВАТЬ, -рую, -руешь; нсв. [от франц. diriger] (чем). 1.
>   **Управлять оркестром или хором**.

**Не музыкой и не композиторами.**

(++)
Хотя там есть оговорка...

> что или чем. Проф. Управлять коллективом при исполнении музыкального
>   произведения. **Д. оперу. Д. симфонию Бетховена**.

Но тут уже дебри профессиональные...
Впрочем, все равно, не "Чайковским". Там другой смысл...